# How to remove or fadeout selected div parta after success by jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to remove selected div part by click on cancel button php code

```
while($fetch_user_info= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_client))
{
  <div class="col-sm-12 m-t-20 insight_box">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm cancel_insights"  value="<?php echo $c_id;?>">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm " onclick="window.open('<?php echo $url.'?pan='.$jh1_pan ?>', '_blank')">Yes, On board now!</button>
  </div>
}
?>
```

Jquery :

```js
$('.cancel_insights').click(function() {
  var c_id = $(this).val();
  $.post('url', {
    'c_id': c_id,
    'action': 'action'
  }, function(data, status) {
    if (data == 'true') {
      $(this).find('.insight_box').fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: <script>
 
 $('.cancel_insights').click(function(){
 
  var c_id=$(this).val();
  
  $.post('url',{'c_id':c_id,'action':'action'}, function(data,status){
   
   if(data=='true')
   {
     $(this).find('.insight_box').fadeOut();
   }    
  });
 });
    </script>

Comment: What do you mean by selected? Can you be more clear?

Comment: hi i mean i want to remove div section in which i click on cancel button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change
`$(this).find('.insight_box').fadeOut();`

into this

```
$(this).parent().fadeOut();
```

Comment: hi it work before ajax post, but not in data true condition.

Comment: Then try using $.ajax instead of $.post

Comment: add the line in the success function of $.ajax

Comment: $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"url",
     data:{'c_id':c_id},
     success:function(data)
     {if(data=='true')
       {

                                                                                             $(this).parent().fadeOut(1000); 
       }
                 }
       });

Comment: have you print or echo "true" in the target page?

Comment: try an alert in the condition before the fadeout line, make sure it works

Comment: or try using the success function without argument . ie:    success:function(){$(this).parent().fadeOut(1000);}

Comment: $('.cancel_insights').click(function(){
 
 var c_id=$(this).val(); 
        
     $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"url",
        data:{'c_id':c_id},
     
success:function(){
      $(this).parent().fadeOut(1000);}      
    });
   
 });

Comment: i tried all this ...alert is shown in success condition. but fadeout not working.

Comment: try storing $(this) into a variable before ajax call and use the variable to fadeout. ie; variable.parent().fadeOut();

Comment: yes its done.as you suggest me store $(this) in variable before Ajax calling.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event so when the button is clicked it gets its parent and removes it, like so

```
$(".cancel_insights").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: hi it work before ajax post, but not in data true condition.